# How will Salesforce's move to SHA-256 for certs impact Mobile SDK users?

Tags: mobilesdk, ssl, encryption, certificates

Is Mobile SDK 3.0 compatible with the new SSL certificates coming out later this year? If not, what changes should be applied by iOS users of the Mobile SDK?

EDIT: Thanks to Gaurav below for this link:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=HTTPS-Security-Certificate-Switch-from-SHA-1-to-SHA-256-hash-algorithms&language=en_US

When I run the test suggested by that link within the app, then the UIWebView that normally presents the OAuth page shows the green "test passed" instead. I don't see either of the results for pass/fail that that link suggests to look for. (The section headed 'To test the compatibility of an API client that uses REST to communicate with Salesforce:') Surely that only tests the UIWebView. How does one go further to test SFRestRequest?

EDIT: OK I'm making progress with this...

request.endpoint can be set to include the protocol and it still works e.g.

```
request.endpoint = @"https://sha2test.salesforce.com/services/data/";
```

instead of

```
request.endpoint = @"services/data/";
```

What I get back looks very similar to a test pass as defined by the link above. Not certain if is is though.

### Request

### GET "https://sha2test.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/Document/01513000003PgdZAAS/Body"

### Response

[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
, [The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 401.)]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding is that it will not impact apps built using the Mobile SDK 3.0 as it already supports SHA-256 in its [libraries](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/tree/master/libs/SalesforceSecurity/SalesforceSecurity). However, you still need devices/ browsers meet the compatibility criteria for SHA-256.

[image]

You can find more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=HTTPS-Security-Certificate-Switch-from-SHA-1-to-SHA-256-hash-algorithms&language=en_US).

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, that's helpful and I have edited my question.